# How to get public google calendars grouped by category?

Tags: google-calendar-api

Is it possible to get list of **public** calendars grouped by category (holidays, sport, other) like at `Settings -> Add calendar -> Browse calendar of interest`

1. I've already try to use `calendarList` endpoint but it is return only chosen calendars.But I need to get all calendars grouped by category.
2. Also I try to group it according to id, for example, from calendar id `epl_6149_%45verton#sports@group.v.calendar.google.com` we understand that main group is sport but there is some problem with `epl_6149_%45verton`. This is `English Premier League -> Everton`. How can I get it in human understandable form?

Comment: https://calendar.google.com/calendar/r/settings/browsecalendars?pli=1

Comment: Don't think this feature exist yet. You can file a feature request on https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new